# If-Else Statement not working - syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm starting to write a script that is solely a file manager, and I am setting a function asking the user to set their preferred text editor, and it always ends with an error message:

```
/home/user/bin/manager: line 12: syntax error near expected token 'fi'
/home/user/bin/manager: line 12: 'fi'
```

This is the code:

```
#!bash/bin
#File managing shell
editor() {
read -p "What file editor would you like to use?    (Nano)  or  (Vi)m   " answer
export $answer=$(echo "$answer" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
if [ [ "$answer" -eq "nano" && "vi" && "vim" && "emacs" ] ]
then
editor="$answer"
else
echo "This is embarassing, I didn't understand your input..."
editor ()
fi
}
echo -e "" #this area tells the user he commands and etc. it takes forever to type...
sleep 1
editor()
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: 1) no need for double `[ [ ` and `] ] ` , 2) you should try a while loop rather than a recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use `#!/bin/bash` as shebang.
- no need for `[ [` ... `] ]`
- `"$answer" -eq "nano" && "vi" && "vim" && "emacs"` will not test answer againt those four words.

function definition

```
while read -p "What file editor would you like to use?    (Nano)  or  (Vi)m   " answer
do 
  answer=$(echo "$answer" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
  case $answer in 
  ( nano | vi | vim | emacs )
     $answer ;
     ## OR
     export EDITOR=$answer
     break 
     ;;
    ( * )
     echo "This is embarassing, I didn't understand your input..."
     ;;
   esac
done
```

- this will check that answer is one of the four valid editor.
- value is returned in EDITOR
- `export $answer=` is likely to fail (first time) or give unexpected result (next time)
- use `$answer` to call editor ( or `$answer "$myfile"` ),
- use `export EDITOR=$answer` to set it,
- or better yet `export EDITOR=$(which $answer)`.

Comment: I didn't even get to    $editor "file name"

Comment: I will case it.

Answer (score 2):

The second and third

```
editor ()
```

should just be

```
editor
```

You need the parentheses only for the function definition.

The parser for bash is complaining about a missing `';'` after the `()`, but that's only part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you but I found that my lower casing didn't work so it never understands the input, and I need to edit "(Nano)  or  (Vi)m" and add "  (Emacs)" ...  So I guess I will case-esac it.

Comment: I only needed to change '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'     to      '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'

Comment: I still need to case it...